# AngularJS ui-scroll not working (Cannot set property 'overflowY' of undefined)

Tags: angularjs, ui-scroll

New to AngularJS. Following ui-scroll is not working. Appreciate any help.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PVCWRf1DaVtt4j7z15wx?p=preview

Trying implement simple ui-scroll without any jquery libraries. Below is sample code making it to work so that i can expand it to be implemented in app.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hospital</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-scroll.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scroll.css">

    <div ng-app="scrollerTestApp" ng-controller="ScrollerController">
      <div  ui-scroll="movie in movieDataSource">
        <h2>{{ movie.description }}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**scroll.js**

```
var appModule = angular.module('scrollerTestApp', ['ui.scroll'])
  .controller('ScrollerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.movieDataSource = {
      get: function(index, count, callback) {
        var i, items = [],
          item;

        var min = 1;
        var max = 100;

        for (i = index; i < index + count; i++) {
          if (i < min || i > max) {
            continue;
          }
          item = {
            description: "Item : " + i,
            imageURL: "http://placehold.it/96x96&text=" + i
          };
          items.push(item);
        }
        callback(items);
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is you're lack of `ui-scroll-jqlite`.

According to the documentation:

> File dist/ui-scroll-jqlite.js houses implementations of the above
>   methods and also has to be loaded in your page. Please note that the
>   methods are implemented in a separate module 'ui.scroll.jqlite' and
>   this name should also be included in the dependency list of the main
>   module.

that said, I let your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4DQhe6) edited.

Hope it helps ;).

Answer (score 0):

Since `angular-ui-scroll` **v1.6.0** the `ui.scroll.jqlite` module was deprecated. All necessary instructions had been incapsulated into `ui.scroll` module. So, the best solution would be to upgrade the `angular-ui-scroll` dependency.

---

If you are using `angular-ui-scroll` before v1.6.0, you should add `ui.scroll.jqlite` module to the App explicitly:

```
angular.module('scrollerTestApp', ['ui.scroll.jqlite', 'ui.scroll'])
```

Also, it means that `ui-scroll-jqlite[.min].js` should be added to your scripts/build before `ui-scroll[.min].js`.